# explode() only returns first array element

Tags: php

I have the following function

```
function split_email($email){
    return explode("@", $email);
}
```

and want to split an email and display it as such:

```
$email = split_email($row['email']);
echo $email[0];
echo $email[1];
```

Oddly, I get the error of `Undefined offset: 1`. When I try this on the string `email@website.com`.

I know it is finding the @ symbol as if I only try and acess `$email[0]` I will get the first portion. What is going on here?

Comment: tried `var_dump(split_email($row['email']))` to see what's really coming back?

Comment: Its late... but that should work absolutely fine. If you echo $row['email'] does that work?

Comment: Working for me [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1ff581ab2df4215c63b30958c5dcc6e38d5a786).

Comment: The problem indeed was with `$row['email'];`. One of my databases rows had a `NULL` value. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely there is a problem with the email you are passing to the function , try this one to see the problem.

```
function split_email($email) {

        print_r($email);
       return explode("@", $email);
}
```